# Deployment Target Version option missing in VS2015

Tags: ssis

It seems that the Deployment Target Version option is missing in my Visual Studio 2015
I see this instead:

[image]

So, I can`t select the Target Server Version

Can someone help me in this please?
Thanks in advance

Lena

Comment: Make sure that you are using the latest version of SSDT for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Hi! Can you please tell me how to check this?

Comment: Click on Configuration Properties (one level higher). That's where I see TargetServerVersion. I also have  a General tab, which is the same as if I just click on Configuration Properties.

Comment: @LenaMeer, any update on this?

Comment: No, sorry, I can`t find this option..The only thing I`m left with is to try and install VS 2017...